# Error trying to use image_science in a rails project on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image-science

I have a rails 3.0.20 app running with rvm on ruby 1.9.3p327. My Gemfile reads:

```
gem 'image_science', :git => 'git://github.com/asynchrony/image_science.git'
```

and Gemfile.lock has its version as:

```
remote: git://github.com/asynchrony/image_science.git
revision: dc36ddaadc46aecdef907de3c41a9d14d28ba8d8
specs:
  image_science (1.3.2.1.Asynchrony)
```

I cannot seem to start my app without removing image_science, since I keep getting this error:

```
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
rake aborted!
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/image_science-dc36ddaadc46/lib/image_science/extension.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE - /home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/image_science-dc36ddaadc46/lib/image_science/extension.so
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/image_science-dc36ddaadc46/lib/image_science.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/umar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@a_proj/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/home/umar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@a_proj/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/umar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@a_proj/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/umar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@a_proj/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/home/umar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@a_proj/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/home/umar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@a_proj/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/home/umar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@a_proj/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/home/umar/myprojects/a_proj/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/umar/myprojects/a_proj/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/umar/myprojects/a_proj/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/umar/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the required libraries (FreeImage and RubyInline) to make ImageScience work. ([ImageScience RDoc](http://docs.seattlerb.org/image_science/))

By the way, I assume that you don't use mini_magick or rmagick because you don't have access to an imagemagick or graphicsmagick installation.

Perhaps you should try to use one of these two, because ImageScience has not been updated for a while.

Hope this helps.